# Multiple instances per type: how to do it better?

Tags: haskell

I have some data types for which I need `ToJSON` instances, but I need to send those objects to different pears which expects different representation. So, I need multiple (different) instances per data type. How to achieve this? I know only a way with `newtype` wrapping.

Is there any way to use different instances of the same type in the same module / program for the same type without using `newtype`? Also I think about something like:

```hs
data Peer = PeerA | PeerB | ...

class AsJSON peer a where
  asJSON :: peer -> a -> Value
```

Such class `AsJSON` will replace `ToJSON`: I'll need to implement such instances but to use `AsJSON a =>` of my own class constraint instead of standard `ToJSON a =>` anywhere...

So, what is the best (more preferable in your opinion) way to do it? How usually do you solve such task?

Comment: another idea is to solve it on modules level but it looks very error prone

Comment: I don't think there's anything better than a `newtype` here.

Comment: I think not using `ToJSON` is significantly better here. You're allowed to write functions to convert your type to `Value` without making them part of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

The simplest option is to eschew typeclasses and simply write functions. This has the benefit of simplicity. However, it makes it harder to write abstract functions. Consider the function `callEndpoint_ :: ToJSON a => a -> Url -> IO ()`. This function must be rewritten to have the type signature `callEndpoint_ :: (a -> Value) -> a -> IO ()`, and you must manually pass the function around if you have a whole stack of these generic functions.

Your solution is similar, in that you'd have to pass around a `Peer` value in order to call `asJson`; you might as well pass around the function.

Newtypes solve most of these issues. You can write generic functions, and then just wrap your data in the newtype and pass that to the function and it will automatically call the right instance methods.

Another solution would be to use Phantom Types. https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type covers the basics, but you would essentially write:

```
data MyData a = MyData Int String Float --'a' is NOT used in the right hand side.

data Peer = PeerA | PeerB

instance ToJSON (MyData PeerA) where 
    ...
instance ToJSON (MyData PeerB) where
    ...
```

This will require enabling the `FlexibleInstances` extension (and probably also `FlexibleContexts`).

You can also use `KindSignatures` and `DataKinds` to make this more strict; then you can write `data MyData (a :: Peer) = ...` and then the compiler will allow you to write the signature `MyData PeerA` but not the signature `MyData Int`.

Comment: Aha, I forgot about phantom types, this solution looks very good, because types becomes "self-documented", when you see this `a` type param, you understand that this type has some "variability" (so, possible you should to pay attention to its ToJSON instances, they may be different)....

Comment: That being said, I do think that perhaps newtypes are the cleaner, more readable solution.